# GCR (Google Cloud Run) enable http

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there any way to enable http on gcr?
I do have a npm package, that can't talk https.

```sh
(node:12037) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: RequestError: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL]: Protocol "https:" not supported. Expected "http:"
    at MoneroRpcConnection.sendJsonRequest (/home/user/Projects/jointed.gitlab.io/docker/node_modules/monero-javascript/src/main/js/rpc/MoneroRpcConnection.js:124:18)
```

If I do request the http endpoint, I get redirected:

```sh
(node:11179) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: StatusCodeError: 302 - ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Run exposes only an HTTPS endpoint.  It might be possible to reach it through HTTP if you provide an HTTP proxy such as Cloud Endpoints or Apigee or roll your own reverse proxy with a Compute Engine and a WebServer or software (Node JS Express or Python Flask for example).

References

- [Invoking with an HTTPS Request](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/https-request)